# Consecutively intersect two sets of intervals

Tags: algorithm

We have two sets of intervals, A and B.

Every inteval in A is described by two positive real numbers `{A1start,A1end},{A2start,A2end},...,{Anstart,Anend}`. `Anend` is alsways > `Anstart`. Intervals in A MAY overlap.

The set B is only decribed by two values: interval length and interval distance. The interval length is the delta of every interval, i.e. `Bnend - Bnstart`, and is > 0. Interval distance is the distance between any two `Bnstart`. Intervals in B may NOT overlap.

We know that on any interval `{A1start,Anend}` the number of intervals in A and B SHOULD be equal.

The question is: on the interval of `{A1start,Anend}` can we intersect B with A *consecutively*? i.e. `B1` must intersect `A1`, `B2` must intersect `A2` etc. It is fine if any B intersects any other A besides its designated one.

I have worked out two algorithm rules and currently stuck:

1. B rules allow us to calculate the min and max number of intervals on any `{A1start,Anend}`, we use it to discard the cases when the number of intervals in A and B is unequal.
2. If any gap in A is greater than B distance, we discard this case since at least one B won't intersect any A.

What other conditions must be true for these two sets to intersect consecutively?

Comment: Note that there is no direct question here. What exactly do you want help on?  It will probably be off-topic (too broad) for SO anyway.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, added the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

- Dilate all the intervals in A by the interval length of B by subtracting the length from all the `Anstart` values. You can think of A as now defining all the valid positions where an interval in B can start.
- The problem is now whether you can intersect a series of points (B) spaced a given distance apart with a set of intervals (A). You can solve this by intersecting `A1` with `A2` offset by `-distance`, `A3` offset by `-2distance` ... `An` offset by `-(n-1)distance`. If the intersection of all these intervals is non-empty then an intersection of A and B is possible.

Comment: With an additional condition that every B has P probability of existing, and if it doesn't we know that there is no corresponding A, am I right to assume that on the second step of your solution instead of offsetting As by -(n-1)distance I can shred all As by B distance, and if those shredded bits intersect the sets indeed intersect.

Comment: I'm not sure. In the case that there is a probability for each B existing, are you asking if an intersection is guaranteed (for every combination of Bs existing), or just possible (for at least one)? For second case it's easy - just assume they all exist. For other case, if a given B doesn't exist, do you step past it and leave a space, and skip corresponding A? In this case the remaining ones should match up the same. If you don't leave a space, it's possible to create a non-intersection isn't it, unless all As are as large as B distance time A count? Perhaps I don't understand you correctly.

Comment: It is the second case you described: if a B doesn't exist, we skip the corresponding A and leave an empty space. The problem is that in this case we don't have the factor by which we should multiply the distance to offset each A to get an intersection.